# Split string into substring with component separated by string swift

Tags: swift, string, split, substring

I have a string as shown below,

let `newString : String = "12","34","56","78","910","1112","1314","1516","1718","1920","2122","2324","2526","2729".`

i want to separate string with `"4 string each"` string e.g. `"12","34","56","78" and "910","1112","1314","1516"` and so on.

Can we achieve this by using range or something else?

**Note :**- newString is not static data it will come from webservice

Comment: you can seprate it with , and then merge it again for every 4 string objects.

Comment: @PatelJigar it would be great if you can provide any example

Comment: use `joinWithSeparator` and `componentsSeparatedByString`

Comment: `let newString : String = "12","34","56","78","910","1112","1314","1516","1718","1920","2122","2324","2526","2729"` is not valid Swift. Did you mean to say that you have an *array* of strings? Or are the quotation marks part of the string itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this way, first create array from String, then make chunk array from it and then join the string from array.

```
let newString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"
let array = newString.components(separatedBy: ",") // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
let chunkSize = 4
let chunksArray = stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(array[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, array.count)])
}
let subArray = chunksArray.map { $0.joined(separator: ",") }
// ["1,2,3,4", "5,6,7,8", "9,10,11,12"]
```

Edit: You can merge last two action with single like this way.

```
let subArray = stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: chunkSize).map { 
    array[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, array.count)].joined(separator: ",") 
}
// ["1,2,3,4", "5,6,7,8", "9,10,11,12"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nirav D cheers i was trying with chunksArray but couldn't found solution for Swift 3

Comment: You could also say `let subArray = stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: chunkSize).map { array[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, array.count)].joined(separator: ",") }`. Saves creating intermediate arrays.

Comment: @Hamish Thanx for the suggestion, edited answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

First generate an array from string:

```
let newString = "1,2,3,4,1234,1235,1236,1238,678,679"    
let newStringArray = newString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

Then run for loop and add string using `joinWithSeparator`

Answer (score 0):

You could split string the by `,` like: `let strArr = newString.components(separatedBy: ",")`, then split the `strArr` to arrays containing 4 elements, and join each resulting array by `,`. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: can you please write example here